# play sound if certain image is loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a sound file that I would like him to be heard only if a certain image on my page is loaded.

how can I manage that?

what do I need to add to document ready?

Comment: @Jack Why? jQuery + HTML5 = Winning combination. Let's kick flash from web dev

Comment: Really, flash? With all of the html5 goodness available and Adobe dropping support for mobile?

Comment: See [Play Sound Javascript/Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421424/play-sound-javascript-jquery?rq=1) and [Jquery check if image is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069126/jquery-check-if-image-is-loaded?rq=1).

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

Comment: @roXon: except that jQuery+HTML5 still isn't close to what flash can do. It's slow (dom manipulation and such), it's buggy, it's near impossible to get anything significantly complex to run the same in every browser, basic tools are *just* coming out for making actual applications, standards are so far off (from being standardized and adopted) that it's a crapshoot if something will even work, yet alone work right. Yes, flash is dead. It may be dieing, but there's still a lot that you can't do well in HTML5 that is borderline trivial in flash... Not saying not to prefer JS, but boo to FUD...

Comment: Open this link it will solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483455/play-sound-when-message-received

Answer (score 3):

Include the [`ImagesLoaded()`](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin.

**HTML**

```
<audio id="my_sound">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">

  Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>
```

**jQuery**

```
var audio = document.getElementById('my_sound');

$('img#my_image').imagesLoaded(function(e) {
    audio.play();
});
```

Comment: This is not good solution according to answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded. If image is loaded from cache there is a chance that event won't start.

Comment: Based on your comments I changed the `load()` event to `imagesLoaded()`, a jQuery plugin used to create event handlers when an image is loaded.

Comment: what should I put here: img#my_image ,  my image name is greenbell.png, so :img#greenbell.png - what should I put insted img#

Comment: Add to your '<img src="greenbell.png" alt=""/>' ID attribute named- my_image

Comment: @jimmywho `<img src="greenbell.png" id="my_image" alt="" />`

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/izunin/2/edit)***

HTML:

```
<img class="alertSound" src="img.jpg" /> 


<audio id="imgLoadedSound" src="loaded.ogg">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

JS:

```
$('img.alertSound').load(function(){
     $('#imgLoadedSound').get(0).play();
});
```

Or better:
***[JsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/izunin/6/edit)***

```
$(function() {

    function imgIsLoaded() {

      var audio = new Audio('loaded.ogg');
      var img = new Image().src = this;
      img.onload = function(){
        audio.play();
      };

    }

    $('img.alertSound').each(function() {
        if( this.complete ) {
            imgIsLoaded.call( this );
        } else {
            $(this).one('load', imgIsLoaded);
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: it's working,thank you,my problem is that the image I point this sound to is only loaded on a div that is been discover after clicking on something in the page,at that point this code is not working

Comment: @jimmywho At what point?

Comment: the point when the image is been show on the page,the image only been show when I open a certain div and not on 'on load'

Comment: I answered your question. For other questions please write a new one